# Render .NET controls in DirectX window

Tags: .net, controls, directx, render

Is it possible to render a .NET window (or a bunch of controls) in a windowed DirectX frame?

What I want to do is to protect some sensitive data against screenscraping / spyware by having it render in a DirectX instance, to make it immune against the screencapturing API the OS provides.

Is this even possible?
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Reinout

Comment: Spyware will be able to capture the window, although it will make it more difficult. Take a look at the following for an example of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962142/take-screenshot-of-directx-full-screen-application