# screen pixel testing not as expected (win32 c++)

Tags: c++, windows, testing, screenshot, pixel

I tried to write this short sloppy code to play a game for me on my screen but it's not responding as I expected.
After suspecting that it might be something related to my window, I tried letting it stare it mspaint instead and it had no reaction.

The program takes in 7 points for observation, and you press shift to begin. Then it should click any pixels near the color I have in comments there above the rgb stuff. I've tried loosening those ranges but I did notice it click something of the wrong color once.
When I traced the color values it was getting, I noticed a lot of them were black, which is odd because there are no black pixels in the front window.

(I'm using windows7 if that means anything)

Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void ClickAt(int x,int y){
    SetCursorPos( x, y );
    Sleep(10);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0,0,0);
    Sleep(10);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0,0,0);
    Sleep(10);
}

int absDist(int a,int b)
{
    int diff = a - b;
    if( diff<0 ) diff*=-1;
    return diff;
}

LPPOINT mouse;
POINT testPoints[7];

int main()
{
    mouse = new POINT;
    BYTE state=FALSE;
    BYTE prevState=FALSE;

    cout<< "Hello, let\'s get ready to play the game.\n";


    cout<< "Please provide your click-points by clicking them now.\n";

    int clicksFound = 0;

    while(true){
        state = (bool)GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON);
        if(state!=prevState){
            prevState=(bool)state;
            if((bool)state != 0){
                // a click happened
                GetCursorPos(mouse);
                testPoints[clicksFound].x = mouse->x;
                testPoints[clicksFound].y = mouse->y;
            }else{
                clicksFound++;
                if( clicksFound>=7 ) 
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<< "\aGreat! Now press shift when you\'re ready to start.\n";
    cout<< "(You\'ll press space to quit.)\n";

    while(true)
    {
        if( (bool)GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) )
            break;
    }

    cout<< "\aNow playing the game.\n";

    COLORREF myPixel;
    int r,g,b;

    while(true)
    {
        HDC scrn = GetDC(NULL);

        // R 225
        // G 141
        // B 35
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
            myPixel = GetPixel(scrn,testPoints[i].x,testPoints[i].y);
            if( myPixel==CLR_INVALID )
                cout<< "invalid\n";


            r = GetRValue(myPixel);
            g = GetGValue(myPixel);
            b = GetBValue(myPixel);

            if( absDist(r,225)<20 && absDist(g,141)<20 && absDist(b,35)<20 )
            {
                cout<< "click\n";
                ClickAt(testPoints[i].x,testPoints[i].y);
            }
        }

        Sleep(20);

        if( (bool)GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) )
            break;

        ReleaseDC(NULL,scrn);
    }

    cout<< "\aThank you for playing the game.\n";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks okay to me.  I've deleted my answer as it was not helpful.  Maybe someone else has a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Am I wrong or 
    ReleaseDC(NULL,scrn);
dont get released, because this line is after the "break" in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If the other program isn't using GDI to draw to the screen (most games use Direct3D or OpenGL), then you can't read the pixels that way.

This answer might help you: [Take screenshot of DirectX full-screen application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962142/take-screenshot-of-directx-full-screen-application/1963550#1963550)