# C++ Windows screenshot

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to write a tool to captrue screenshots. Anyway, to see how other tools work I have tried some other tools. Like nircmd.exe. I am automatically capturing screenshots once in a while. Problem is it doesn't capture the WoW window when it's active.

[image]

WoW runs as fullscreen. But look at the top left corner. That's all it will show. Instead it will show something else. I blocked out the unneccesary parts of the screen. For information: it showed skype that was not minimized. But... WoW was active. Any idea what the problem could be?

I will also be happy if someone points me at a tool that can solve my problem. This seems like a complicated problem to solve with my own code considering all the other tools fail as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962142/take-screenshot-of-directx-full-screen-application

Comment: My 2 cents: http://pngshot.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Capturing fullscreen is not trivial. It's a own mode at device level. The OS does not have APIs for that. You have to "break into" the target process and hook functions of the graphics API the application uses.

Try [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) if you are not interested in programming it yourself.